# GtkWindow not being recognized as such for fileselector - C

Tags: c, gtk

I'm trying to make a test version of a C program in which the user can load a game level using the GTK file selector.  It seems to work, and does open the fileselector window, but crashes when the user tries to select a file. The issue seems to be that the GtkWindow is not being recognized as a GtkWindow, despite being declared as:

```
GtkWidget *window;
window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL); //initialize window
```

I then save it to the window pointer in the gui struct:

```
typedef struct gui gui_t;

struct gui {
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *frame;
    GtkWidget *menu_bar;
    GtkWidget *drawing_area;
    GtkWidget *vbox;
    level_t *game;
};
```

Which is then passed to the load_menu callback below, which currently just attempts to print the selected filename:

```
void gui_load_menu(gpointer data) {

    gui_t *gui = (gui_t *)data;

    GtkWindow *window = (GtkWindow *)(gui->window);

    GtkWidget *dialog;

    dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new("Load Level", GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN, GTK_STOCK_CANCEL, GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,GTK_STOCK_OPEN, GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT, NULL);

    if(gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog)) == GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT) {
        char *filename = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(dialog));

        fprintf(stdout, "%s", filename);
    }
}
```

These were the particular runtime errors:

> (guitest:4445): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid uninstantiatable type `guchar' in cast to`GtkWindow'
>
> (guitest:4445): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_window_set_transient_for: assertion `parent == NULL || GTK_IS_WINDOW (parent)' failed

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: run the whole thing with `--g-fatal-warnings` and use `catchsegv` or `gdb` to get a trace / line where it crashes. Also place some `g_assert (GTK_IS_WINDOW (foo));` tests

Comment: @drahnr I added an assertion checking if window is a window (I have access to the source), and it that assertion failed. I looked a little deeper and `data` is null. Here's the callback we're using: `g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(load), "activate", G_CALLBACK(gui_load_menu), gui);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the correct signature for the callback, which should be

`void gui_load_menu(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)`

Each callback can have a different signature and you need to look at the documentation for the signal you use to see what it is. I'm presuming in this case `load` is a GtkMenuItem, the documentation is here: http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkMenuItem.html#GtkMenuItem-activate